# Grouping n values to m categories preserving order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have n values which are needed to categorize into m categories preserving a particular order.

**Example**

Monday- 13

Tuesday- 5

Wednesday- 4

Thursday- 4

Friday- 2

Saturday- 11

Sunday- 1

How can I categorize these 7 values to 5 groups preserving the order Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun

Comment: Can you give a smaller example where you can make it clear what you are asking for?  For all I know, (Mon - 13), (Tues - 5), (Wed - 4), (Thurs - 4), (Fri - 2, Sat-11, Sun - 1) works

Comment: Consider the same example. I want to find the all such combinations( You mentioned only one). I can try manually as you did. But is there a way to find all such combinations( number of all the combinations) using a formula ?

Comment: I'm saying, its not clear what you mean about "preserving the order"... How does this question vary from, say, asking in how many ways you can distribute $13$ chocolate chip cookies, $5$ peanut butter cookies, ..., $1$ oatmeal raisin cookie to $5$ children?

Comment: So in the example you mentioned there is no order. Take the example I mentioned. I can group them as (Mon - 13, Tues - 5), (Wed - 4), (Thurs - 4), (Fri - 2), ( Sat-11, Sun - 1) But I can't (Mon - 13, Wed-4), (Tues-5), (Thurs - 4), (Fri - 2), ( Sat-11, Sun - 1) because it breaks the order of Tues, Wed.

Comment: And... so, can you do (Mon-1)(Mon-1)(Mon-1)(Mon-1)(Mon-9 Tues-5 .... Sun-1)?

Comment: The order Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun has to be preserved when grouping the values.

Comment: I get that, i'm wondering what the significance of the values are, if any

Comment: There is only one value for a particular day. That value can't be divided, should be considered as a one value. So I can't break 13 as 1+1+1+1+9. This is the actual problem, I'm trying to solve using a dynamic programming approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278864/optimal-algorithm-to-solve-weighted-disjoint-set-covering-for-fixed-number-of-ro

Comment: So... ignore the "values" then... your question is in how many ways we can put $4$ barriers between Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,Sun, the barriers representing what the groupings are...  For example, Mon|Tues,Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat,Sun represents the grouping (Mon)(Tues,Wed)(Thurs)... etc...   Now... Next question for clarification, can a group be empty?  Either way, the answer will rely on binomial coefficients.

Comment: Yeah exactly, problem is how to put 4 barriers between 7 days. No a group can't be empty. Atleast there should be a one day.

Comment: Got there at last.  @JMoravitz I admire your patience.

Comment: Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*How many ways can I put 4 barriers between 7 days (where no two barriers can be in the same place)?*"

There are six positions... you want to choose 4 of them.

This can be done in "$6$ choose $4$" ways $\binom{6}{4}=15$ ways where $\binom{n}{k}$ denotes the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).